# How to set the Routes and get the GET parameter and value from url in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Suppose i have a controller called user and one method myurl like below. The mylink method generate url list from database with pagination support.

```
class User extends CI_Controller{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function mylink($id){

        /*
            Here I want to delete the url(pseudo code :) )

            //Check 
            IF GET request THEN
                COLLECT the url ID and DELETE the url
                DISPLAY success msg
            ELSE
                DISPLAY success msg
            ENDIF


        /*
            This function will generate url and pagination

        */

        //pagination settings
        $config['base_url'].........
        ......
        ....
        //End of pagination settings (I dont want to write whole text)

        $this->pagination->initialize($config);
        $data['pagination'] = $this->pagination->create_links();

        //call the model function to get the Url data
        $data['urllist'] = $this->user_model->GetUrl($config["per_page"], $id); 

        /*
            urllist contain url details and passed to view. where It will create delete url from respective url id like

            http://example.com/mylink/del/1
            http://example.com/mylink/del/1
            http://example.com/mylink/del/1
            http://example.com/mylink/del/1



        */

        $this->load->view("layout/header");
        $this->load->view("mylink",$data);
        $this->load->view("layout/footer");

    }

}
```

in my routes i have set

```
/*
this is for pagination like

http://example.com/mylink/1
http://example.com/mylink/1
http://example.com/mylink/1

*/
$route['mylink'] = 'user/mylink';
$route['mylink/(:num)'] = 'user/mylink/$1';
$route['mylink/del/(:num)'] = 'user/mylink/$1'; //***** Dont understand here how to set*****
```

But I dont understand how to set the delete url route and make it proper functional. Please help me with this. Thanks